# Permissions for ASP

Tags: iis, asp-classic, iis-7, group-policy

I've inherited quite the intranet, amongst other systems. They were not written by programmers, so there's a fair bit of just getting things to work that was done.

One of the asp pages has worked since I've gotten here, but today all of sudden everyone got an error 500.19. But none of the asp pages in other folders had this issue. On a hunch, I checked the permissions on that folder and a folder that did work. The one that worked is shared to everyone, so we added that to the folder that doesn't work. That seems to have fixed the problem.

I'm wondering however as to the cause. No one changed the permissions, so could it be an issue with group policys that changed?
I also remember setting up IIS almost a decade ago, and then we had to share the folder to the local user. And the root folder is shared to the local user.
Is it possible that due to group policy changes, the share is no longer cascading from the root folder to the subfolders?

Comment: You haven't given us enough information to give a definitive answer, but I'd say, yes it is possible that a change in the group policy could have that effect, but usually if that is the case, unless you change the group policy, it will re-occur when the policy is applied again.

Comment: Sounds like you need to enable friendly error messages to give you more details about what's wrong.  I recommend this page to tell you how.  http://www.chestysoft.com/asp-error-messages.asp